# ls -a or ls -lR shows empty result

Tags: command-line, directory, ls, visual-studio-code

at my `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages`,
I run `sudo ls -a` and it shows empty:

```
$ sudo ls -a
.  ..
```

With `ls -lR` it also shows empty:

```
$ sudo ls -lR
.:
total 0
```

But there is actually stuff there when I open that directory in VS Code:

[image: Screenshot of VS Code, listing files]

Am I understanding the `ls` command incorrectly or there should be more to do to see the result?

Comment: I noticed that in VS Code, your folder name is in capitals (Ubuntu is case sensitive), whereas in `ls` it isn't. Can you double-check that you are looking at the exact same file location in both?

Comment: @cocomac i am sure it is the correct folder name, vscode go all-uppercase in its UI though. If you have python in your machine, help me check it to see the behaviour I am talking about

Comment: For me, that directory you mentioned was empty (both with `ls` and with VS Code)... but the directory `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` is where all the modules got installed.

Comment: oh let me check again, thank you for your support ser